# Get my geolocation and create intent to show it

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, geolocation, maps

I'm tried to get latitude and longitude of my location and i found it. And when i check it, my latitude and longitude was right. But when i tried create google map intent with my latitude and longitude. the map show wrong location.

This is my intent

```
        Builder gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(mess)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("q", label)
                .appendQueryParameter("z", "16");
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri.build());
        startActivity(intent);
```

I've been try to use the other option

```
        String label = "He/She were here!";
        String latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        String longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        String query = latitude + "," + longitude + "(" + label + ")";
        String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
        String uriString = mess + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri );
        startActivity(intent);
```

But both of them show wrong place. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)"));

    startActivity(intent);
```